# Regex to match repeated consonant

Tags: regex, validation

How can I detect with a regular expression if the same consonant is repeated three or more times?

My idea is to match words like `tttool`, `likkke`, or `likkkkke`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There may be shortcuts in certain regex libraries but you can always...

```
b{3,}|c{3,}|d{3,}...
```

Some libs for example let you match using a back reference which may be a tad cleaner...

```
(bcd...)\1{2,}
```

Answer (score 35):

Try this:

```
([b-df-hj-np-tv-z])\1{2,}
```

Explanation:

- `[b-df-hj-np-tv-z]` are all the consonants
- `\1` is the back reference to the 1st group (ie the *same* character)
- `{2,}` means "2 or more of the preceding term", making 3 or more in all

See [live demo](https://rubular.com/r/Nv5RFL67wsfWOt).

Comment: slightly shorter (and arguably more readable) than `[b-df-hj-np-tv-z]` would be `[^aeiou]`

Comment: @phil294 shorter, but not even close to the same: `[^aeiou]` matches *every* character not a vowel (ie punctuation, special chars, the full spectrum). My regex matches only *letters* that are not a vowel.

Answer (score 9):

This is about the shortest regex I could think of to do it:

```
(?i)([b-z&&[^eiou]])\1\1+
```

This uses a regex character class *subtraction* to *exclude* vowels.
I didn't have to mention "a" because I started the range from "b".
Using `(?i)` makes the regex case insensitive.

See a [live demo](http://rubular.com/r/RUFcaKuc19).

Comment: Interesting answer, but trying the same pattern on different sites that show results of a regex in real time, give me **different** results.
(I reworked your regex for a single consonant) → `(?i)[b-z&[^aeiou]]`
Some consider `&` as a `"&"` character, others the last `"]"` as necessary (therefore considered separately), perhaps because they do not recognize `"&&"` as concatenation.
Please, can you tell me something more and to **whom** should I entrust to ensure that the regex is **always** correctly interpreted _(in my program)_?   
   @Bohemian

Comment: @JackT it depends entirely on the language/os/shell/tool/editor and what libraries/options/flags you use. Basically... “it depends” is all that can be said.

Comment: Woah! Super fast! :O 
Well, ok then I'll use the simpler version they recommended.
But yours is the one I prefer!  
Thank you!
EDIT: for those who will read, the pattern I tried with **2** `&` →  `(?i)[b-z&&[^eiou]]`

Comment: @jack this one works in Java and any PCRE compliant tool

Comment: So if my program is in Java will I be 100% secure?

Comment: @jack it works or it doesn’t, but to find out we write unit tests. Test your implementation with a unit test and you’ll immediately confirm it works, and the test will continue to confirm that every time you build.

Comment: This is a strange trick that does not seem well supported; none of the regex flavors [at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/16JzWA/1) support this and it's not the shortest solution either. I just posted [my shorter regex](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60836088/519360) using the double-negative `[^\W_aeiou]`. This saves 3 characters. Using the `i` flag instead of making it inline as `(?i)` would save another 3 characters, assuming your language supports it.

Answer (score 2):

The regex from answer higher `[b-df-hj-np-tv-z])\1{2,}`has a mistake ("y" is fogotten)

It should be `[b-df-hj-np-tv-xz])\1{2,}`

Comment: "Y" wasn't forgotten, in that case it is simply a consonant.

Comment: The letter Y can be regarded as both a vowel and a consonant. [proof from Oxford Dictionary](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/explore/is-the-letter-y-a-vowel-or-a-consonant)

Comment: Isn't it the other way around? I believe v-z is vwxyz, while v-xz is vwxz... Unless we consider y a vowel...

Answer (score 2):

I'd personally solve this in reverse; instead of using `[b-df-hj-np-tv-z]`, I'd go with the double-negative, `[^\W_aeiou]`.

```perl
/([^\W_aeiou])\1\1+/i
```

This has a character class that uses a double negative: match anything except a non-word-character, an underscore, or a vowel. Ignoring non-ASCII vowels, only consonants can match this. Saving a match, the regex then seeks a match of that same consonant (case-insensitive), then one or more again, which brings us to 3+ consecutive consonants.

Answer (score -1):

You can use capture groups with back-references. This will capture repeating symbols:

```
/(
   ([\w])        ## second group is just one symbol
   \2            ## match symbol found in second groups
   \2+           ## match same symbol one or more times
)/x              ## x is just to allow inner comments
```

But not all regexp engines support back-references.

Comment: This does not seek out just consonants. You'll match underscores and vowels, too.