# Java regex allow only consonants

Tags: java, regex, string

i currently have the regex `"^[AEIOU 0-9]+$"` to try and allow only consonants in a substring, however this is not working for me. How could i fix this ?

Edit: the aim of the line is to produce an error if the given string contains anything except consonants, the overall line is:

```
if(authorCode.matches("^[AEIOU 0-9]+$")){
                return "ID Number not valid author";
```

Comment: You cannot expect to match any consonants with `AEIOU 0-9` in the character class.

Comment: Also, `^` and `$` force the regex to match the entire string, not just a substring. Please show some example input/output and the actual code you're using so we can suggest a better way.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [regex expression to match consonant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6338129/regex-expression-to-match-consonant)

Comment: You could negate a selection enclosed in `[` and `]` by starting with `[^`. However, that would really permit *everything* except what you enumerate. Therefore, the explicit enumeration of all consonants using a few ranges is preferable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want something like this: "[b-df-hj-np-tv-z]*". 
Working example: https://regex101.com/r/BcQheO/1

Also see this: [regex expression to match consonant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6338129/regex-expression-to-match-consonant)