# I am trying to make a program to find consonants, vowels and non-alphabet in a string entered by a user

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Chupapi{

static Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

public static void main(String[] args){

    String str = " ";
    int consonant = 0, vowel = 0, non_alpha = 0;
    System.out.print("Enter string: ");
    str = input.nextLine();

    consonant = getConsonantCount(str);
    vowel = getVowelCount(str);
    non_alpha = getNonAlphaCount(str);
  }

}
```

Here is my code, am I doing it in the right way? I'm kinda stuck on what I would use to countdown the consonants, vowels, and non-alphabet.

Comment: i recomand using regex. example for consonant: [regex-to-match-repeated-consonant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6338129/regex-to-match-repeated-consonant)

Comment: Ignoring Java for a moment, how would you do it, if you were a computer? Which steps do you need to do?

Comment: Run a for loop in order to access String characters and check for Consonants, vowels, and non-alphabets and keep them in individual StringBuffer and then print them

Comment: @SL5net thanks for the suggestion I am pretty new when it comes to regex can you hook me up on how will I be constructing it?

Answer (score 1):

So basically you need to run a for loop and check whether the current char is a vowel or a consonant or a non-alphabet character.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        String str = sc.next();
        StringBuffer cosonantSb = new StringBuffer();
        StringBuffer vowelSb = new StringBuffer();
        StringBuffer noAlphabetSb = new StringBuffer();
        for(int idx = 0 ; idx < str.length() ;idx++) {
            char currentChar = str.charAt(idx);
            if( Character.toUpperCase(currentChar) == 'A'  ||
                Character.toUpperCase(currentChar) =='E'  ||
                Character.toUpperCase(currentChar) == 'O' || 
                Character.toUpperCase(currentChar) == 'I' ||
                Character.toUpperCase(currentChar) == 'U' ) {
                vowelSb.append(currentChar);
              }
            else if(Character.toUpperCase(currentChar) >= 'A' &&
                    Character.toUpperCase(currentChar) <= 'Z') {
                cosonantSb.append(currentChar);
            }
            else {
                noAlphabetSb.append(currentChar);
             }
        }
        System.out.println("Consonants :"+cosonantSb);
        System.out.println("Vowels :"+vowelSb);
        System.out.println("Non Aplhabets : "+noAlphabetSb);
        
    }
```

Output:

```
scbalcb1232434knclnsd]12
Consonants :scblcbknclnsd
Vowels :a
Non Aplhabets : 1232434]12
```

Comment: Thank you for this @SwapnilPadaya, but is this a whole new program right other than my program that I posted? I kinda know a little about this what I want to try out is what can I use to my  "consonant = getConsonantCount(str);" and etc...should I also use for loop for them? I appreciate your work tho. Thank you very much.

Comment: Yes, you can use a for loop for them, Well you can also do a little modification in the code I have posted and that will solve your problem.